# How to TextView array

Tags: android

I need to create one textview array, i'd like to show or hide one image depending position.
I'll try to explain it:
I've one layout similar this:

1 2 3 4 5

And depending random value show or hide an image in textview 1 or 2, etc...

I can use:

```
if (a == 4)

 {

t4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ficha);

t1.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

t2.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

t3.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

t5.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

}

else if (a==5)

...

..
```

But i'd like to know, if it's possible to pass the number t(1) using parameters or something similar.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use `List<TextView>  tvList = new ArrayList<TextView>();`
add as many textviews as you like

and this will retrieve a textview  and set background from a list depending on your `a` value :

```
((TextView)tvList.get(a)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ficha+a.....);
```

1st 2nd and so on. you can use Arrays too of course for this purpose.

---

hope it helps abit

Answer (score 2):

you can create textview array like this...

```
TextView tv[];

tv = new TextView[5];
```

and you can use **Switch Case** to show or hide the image...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following snippet;

```
    /*
     * Initializes the textViewArray
     * You can call this from onCreate. 
     */
    private void setViews() {

        // Declared at class level as private TextView[] textViewArray = null;
        textViewArray = new TextView[3];

        textViewArray[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoText0);
        textViewArray[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoText1);
        textViewArray[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoText2);

        // Button to demonstrate the functionality
        switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(imgIndex >= textViewArray.length) {
                    imgIndex=0;
                }

                showTextViewImage(imgIndex++);
            }
        });

        }

    /*
     * Sets the background image only for the textView specified by index
     */
    private void showTextViewImage(int index) {
        setTitle("" + index);

        // First remove the backgroud images from all textviews
        for(TextView textView : textViewArray) {
                textView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        }

        // If you are using a common image for all textViews, use this
        textViewArray[index].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ficha);

        // If you are using different image for every textView, then use this.
        /*
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    textViewArray[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ficha0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textViewArray[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ficha1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textViewArray[2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ficha2);
                    break;
                ...
                ...
                ...
            }
        */
    }
```

Hope, you got the idea.